# jQuery Chosen not showing <select> options

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-chosen, yadcf

I'm using [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to turn a `<select>` item into an `<li>` item that can be styled with CSS.

The issue I'm running into is 2 of the 3 select items I'm trying to turn into lists **are** turning into lists, the problem is their `<option>`s aren't being shown under each respective list. One of the select items is showing its options, and that's the "Show *_* entries" drop-down in the top left of the table. I should mention the 2 items that aren't showing the options are using the "YADCF" plugin that I linked to below.

Any idea why 2 of the 3 lists aren't showing the options? The two select items not showing their options are above the "Office" and "Expeditor" columns.

The two other jQuery plugins I'm using are [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index) and [YADCF](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf).

http://www.dcturano.com/to-do-list/

Comment: It would be better if you put your code here. Off-site links are generally untrusted. Another option would be to recreate your issue at a site like http://www.jsfiddle.com and give us a link to it, as it is better trusted here.

Comment: The fiddle I created couldn't replicate the issue, but I'll post the js I have.

Comment: Can't say what the problem is, but I use dropkick to achieve something similar, so that might be an option if you get stuck.

Comment: I love I can actually create new items in the to do list :-)

Comment: @davidkonrad lol don't add anything too obscene :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integration with chosen was added in 0.6.0 version of yadcf

Just add `select_type: 'chosen'` to the yadcf constructor , here is the showcase page:

[DOM source with chosen example](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_chosen.html)

p.s I am the author of yadcf